# JSPDF javascript not working with Tableau

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api, jspdf

I am trying to print a page in pdf that includes a tableau dashboard. So I am using the JS PDF library to do so. Though the issue is it prints everything except for the Tableau dashboard (within an iframe).

Could you please let me if this works?

Javascript code below:

```
 function loadpdf2(){        
            if ($(document).width() > $(document).height()) {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]); //
            }
            else {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [$(document).height(), $(document).width()]); //
            }
            pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
                pdf.save('webtool.pdf');
            });
        }
```

Tableau iframe below (html code):

```
 <iframe name="iframe" id="youriframeins" src="tableau_sharedlink" height="1000px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, this functionality is not currently supported. You can vote for the idea here: https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1348